# CMD : Clip command Issue

Tags: batch-file, cmd, clip

Working in a call center, i have pretty repetitive logs to write down for each calls, i am trying to build a simple HTA capable of copying the log templates (and emails) to the clipboard with a click.

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to copy a text file in .vbs (?).

So the HTA open the .bat on click with the text name argument (%1). From it's location on a server session (%~dp0) the .batch open the text file (%1) in the folder "Assets".

```
cls
@pushd %~dp0    
clip < %~dp0Assets\%1
@popd
```

I know, i have to work with what i have. But everything works smoothly !

Until i paste the content of the clipboard :

- "d'avoir" becomes "dÆavoir"
- "é" --> "Ú"
- "à" --> "Ó"
- etc ...

I tried Unicode, Ansi and UTF-8, same issue.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: `%~dp0Assets\%1` I think it should be `%~dp0Assets%\1`

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: It's DOS encoding in a command prompt. If Western Europe DOS code page it is the same as ANSI. However all other encodings (US incl) are different to ANSI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing `clip` while the active codepage of the console doesn't match the encoding of the text you're copying to the clipboard.  You should also make sure the text files containing your extended characters are saved in UTF8 format.  In other words, the problem is in the copying, not in the pasting; and everything *doesn't* work as smoothly as you assert.

Try this:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // capture current console codepage to a variable
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('chcp') do set /a cp=%%I

rem // change console codepage to Unicode
chcp 65001 >NUL

rem // copy asset to clipboard
clip < "%~dp0\Assets\%~1" && 2>&1 echo Successfully copied.

rem // revert console to original codepage
chcp %cp% >NUL
```

---

I landed on another magic combination involving PowerShell and .NET methods for juggling the encoding and setting the clipboard contents.  Try this .bat script:

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "infile=%~dp0Assets\%~1"

if not exist "%infile%" (
    2>&1 echo Usage: %~dp0 assetfile
    2>&1 echo ... where assetfile is a file in %~dp0Assets\
    goto :EOF
)

powershell -STA "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

# end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>

add-type -As System.Windows.Forms
$txt = gc $env:infile -encoding UTF8 | out-string

[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($txt)
```

---

Another possible solution would be to store your text snippets within the script itself.  Here's an example demonstrating heredocs within a batch + PowerShell hybrid script (saved with a .bat extension):

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "str=%~1"
powershell -STA "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

# end batch / begin PowerShell #>

$strings = @{
foo = @"
Until i paste the content of the clipboard :

    "d'avoir" becomes "dÆavoir"
"@

bar = @"
"é" --> "Ú"
"à" --> "Ó"
etc ...
"@
} # end $strings collection of heredocs

if (-not $strings[$env:str]) { "$env:str not defined."; exit 1 }

add-type -As System.Windows.Forms
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($strings[$env:str])
```

You'll notice that the heredocs are enclosed with `@"` and `"@`.  Usage: `script.bat foo` or `script.bat bar`

Comment: I get � for the same "special" characters.

Comment: @user2325445 Apparently your console font doesn't contain the glyphs for those extended characters.  Are you pasting into the console, or into a windowed application?

Comment: Windowed application

Comment: Weird.  I tested the script above, copying the "Until i paste the content of the clipboard..." section of your post and pasting it into Notepad++, and it pastes flawlessly.  For what it's worth, the source txt file I'm importing into the clipboard is encoded as UTF-8 with no byte order mark. I'm trying other alternatives using PowerShell and .NET methods, JScript and the `htmlfile` COM object, and an HTA application using `Scripting.FileSystemObject`'s extended arguments for opening as Unicode; and nothing seems to work as well as the bat script in my answer.  I'll keep thinking about it....

Comment: Not exactly a programming solution in the spirit of S.O., but maybe a [portable text macro manager](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/texter_portable) would be a worthwhile alternative to storing a bunch of text files.  I also edited my answer to include another possible solution, including the text you want available to copy to the clipboard as a collection of heredocs within the script itself.

Comment: OK, solution found : it is the "  ... the source txt file I'm importing into the clipboard is encoded as UTF-8 ... " that was extremely important. UTF-8 Works !! Thanks Rojo !

Answer (score 0):

Here is vbscript using the clipboard using IE. As you are in an HTA you already have access to IE window object. This example pastes but `SetData` copies to clipboard. Ignore security as HTAs bypass IE security.

```
Sub Clip
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = 0
    'Have to navigate to a local file to put IE into Intranet Zone, else this will generate security dialog asking permission
    ie.Navigate2 FilterPath & "Filter.html"
    Do 
        wscript.sleep 100
    Loop until ie.document.readystate = "complete"  
    txt=ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    ie.quit
    If IsNull(txt) = true then 
        outp.writeline "No text on clipboard"
    else
        outp.writeline txt
    End If
End Sub
```

The subject is too broad. The point of it is to show how to use your host environment. The key is Component Object Model (COM) and the libraries that are available. You could use Word, Excel access to the clipboard rather than IE's.

Paste this in an HTA.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language=vbscript>
document.write document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Was a real good try but : error : Object required : 'WScript'

Comment: You have to replace scripting host environment with HTA environment. It's `windows.timeout` in IE. Plus in an HTA you don't have to wait anyway.

Comment: I just keep on getting an unspecified error when replacing wscript.sleep 100 with window.setTimeOut "Clip()", 2000. Zes Clip() to use argument text name